# How to update a table of an existing, scaffolded database in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I scaffolded my database succesfully, and I tried adding a field to a model

`

```
public partial class Cotizaciones
{
    private static Random rnd = new Random();
    public Cotizaciones()
    {
        DetalleProductoPersonalizados = new HashSet<DetalleProductoPersonalizado>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Idcotizacion { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaInicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaFin { get; set; }
    public double PrecioFinal { get; set; }
    public string Ubicacion { get; set; } = null!;
    public bool Estado { get; set; }
    public int? PaqueteFk { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(max)")]
    public string? NombreCotizacion = GenerateLetter(); //---> new field

    private static string GenerateLetter()
    {
        StringBuilder fileName = new StringBuilder("");
        for (int i = 0; i <= rnd.NextInt64(1,35); i++)
        {
            fileName.Insert(i, Convert.ToChar(rnd.Next(65, 90)));
        }
        return fileName.ToString();
    }

    [NotMapped]
    [DisplayName("Subir comprobante de pago")]
    public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }

    public virtual Paquete? PaqueteFkNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DetalleProductoPersonalizado> DetalleProductoPersonalizados { get; set; }
}
```

`

However applying migrations said no changes were made, making a new migration and trying to apply it throws me this message

> There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.

Comment: See how all the others are properties and not fields?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Model stuff, with business logic, and EF will not allow this.  You would need to take the "GenerateLetter" piece and move it to a different process, and make your new addition a true property.

You could possibly use a `[Backing Fields][1]` implementation to try and get this working, but it will not do what I think you might think it would do.

You will most likely have to re-think how that GenerateLetter method is called if you want to persist the value to the database.  You could possibly make it a `[computed column][1]`, but you wouldn't have access to Random etc. there.